# Cucumber: On running the code, getting gherkins exception

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber

On trying to run the feature file, getting the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:31)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.IGherkinDialectProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: This sounds like either your POM (or Gradle file) is missing a dependency, or your IDE cannot seem to find it.  Can you let us know which JARs you have already included?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i am using maven project,                                  
           cucumber-core-2.0.1, cucumber-html-0.2.6, cucumber-java-2.0.1, cucumber-junit-2.0.1, cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6, gherkin-2.12.2, hamcrest-all-1.3, junit-4.12, selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

From [this documentation page](https://book2s.com/java/jar/g/gherkin3/download-gherkin3-3.1.0.jar.html) it appears the no class definition found error you are getting is being caused because you do not have the `io.cucumber` JAR on your classpath.  You can try adding the following dependency to your POM file, assuming you are using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven, but just need a plain JAR file somewhere, then you can follow this link to download a JAR directly from the Maven repository:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <!-- JUNIT  and Cucumber Version  -->
    <junit.version>4.13.1</junit.version>
    <cucumber.version>6.10.0</cucumber.version>

    <!-- RestAssured and Hamcrest version  -->
    <rest-assured.version>3.3.0</rest-assured.version>
    <hamcrest.version>2.2</hamcrest.version>

    <!-- Selenium Version  -->
    <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>

    <!--cucumber-expression and gherkin -->
    <cucumber-expression>13.0.0</cucumber-expression>
    <gherkin>19.0.0</gherkin>

    <!--Reports-->
    <cucumber-reporting>5.3.0</cucumber-reporting>
    <reporting-plugin>4.0.56</reporting-plugin>

    <!-- TestNg and Commons  Version  -->
    <testNG.version>7.4.0</testNG.version>

    <cucumber.report.json.location>${project.basedir}/json</cucumber.report.json.location>
    <generated.report.location>${project.build.directory}/cluecumber-report</generated.report.location>

</properties>

<dependencies>


    <!--05.  Junit for Run test -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!--06.  Cucumber Junit for Run test -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--07.  Cucumber Pico container For dependency Injection-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--08.  cucumber-core is a Core library for the Cucumber BDD app-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--09. Cucumber-java is used to write them using annotated methods and also use Api Level Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--11.  cucumber-TestNg  can be executed in parallel using TestNG and Maven-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--12.  TestNG is a testing framework inspired from JUnit and NUnit but introducing some new functionalities that make it more powerful and easier-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testNG.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

   
     <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.0</version>
     </dependency>
   


     <!--13.  selenium-support - Selenium automates browsers. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--14.  selenium-java - Selenium automates browsers. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-expressions</artifactId>
          <version>10.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
               -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
          <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber5-adapter</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
      </dependency>
   
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>


<build>


    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
            <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>reporting</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
                <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-report</generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
                <expandBeforeAfterHooks>true</expandBeforeAfterHooks>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*TestRun.java</include>
                    <include>**/*run00*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <jsonFile>**/*.json</jsonFile>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>true</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                        <mergeFeaturesById>true</mergeFeaturesById>
                        <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                        <skipEmptyJSONFiles>true</skipEmptyJSONFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>




    </plugins>


</build>
```

[image]